# Car rig in blender and importing to Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender, blender-2.61

I am new to unity and my question is: I am trying to import the rigged car model from blender 2.6 to unity 3.5. but when i import to unity the car physics and it's rig unable to act the same way how it's been created in blender. Please let me know do i need to setup all of the physics and rig in unity once again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using mesh collider ? Mesh collider only works right if you have a static object.

My recomendation is to use a box collider on car and the whell collider on whells, you can import the animation, and call them using Animation.Play("animation"), and put this on the  if (Input.GetKeyDown (Keyboard.A)) for example. Or you can do the animation on unity, pressing CTRL+6

You can take a look on  [this](http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/car-tutorial) Unity tutorial for Car games.

Comment: If you have any another question of the animation, post here and I can help you =)

Comment: Thanks Fred, is there any tutorial which shows from making 3d model of a car and its rig and import to Unity, I believe what am following now its not accurate or not even approximate (pieces found on the internet).